# Install and connect Couchbase Client ASP.NET

Tags: nosql, couchbase

I really cant connect my c# client with  couchbase DB. I realy dont know what i do wrong.. Also why my server name is 192.168.1.3 and whats what means?

Server:

[image]

Creating test db:
[image]

Check firewall port:
[image]

My web.config: 
[image]

And finally my C# code:
[image]

Once again, what im doing wrong and what that server name means?

Comment: Just noting that some suggestions are at http://www.couchbase.com/forums/thread/cant-connect-remote-server

Comment: Just a heads up for other people who run into a similar issue. The bucket name is case sensitive, check the exact spelling of your bucket name to see if it resolves your issue.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I am stuck on the EXACT same thing, what was wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap URI you're using in the app.config should not be /pools/test.  Actually, I'm surprised that's giving results.  The main pool is always default so it should be either /pools or /pools/default.

Comment: It works because the client has the sanity check code to strip off the path after pools and set it to /pools.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, Mike737. I did not notice the case for one character and was kind of lost  there. Correcting the case of bucket name fixed my issue.